# Looking inside a curried function in R (reverse currying?)

Tags: r, functional-programming, currying

suppose I have

```
library(functional)
f = function(x, p) { x^p }
f2 = Curry(f, p=2)
```

Is there a way to find out what p was set to given only f2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See if this is useful. Essentially the p argument is carried in the environment of the body of Curry()-ied function:

```
> body(f2)
do.call(FUN, c(.orig, list(...)))
> body(f2)[[1]]
do.call
> body(f2)[[3]]
c(.orig, list(...))
> body(f2)[[3]][[2]]
.orig
> eval(body(f2)[[3]][[2]])
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object '.orig' not found
> eval(body(f2)[[3]][[2]], environment(f2) )
$p
[1] 2
```

As BrodieG comments these could be used in a programming attack on the problem:

```
> environment(f2)$.orig
$p
[1] 2

> environment(f2)$.orig$p
[1] 2
```

To see why I didn't stumble upon that initially compare:

```
> ls( envir=environment(f2) )
[1] "FUN"
> ls( envir=environment(f2) ,all.names=TRUE)
[1] "..."   ".orig" "FUN"
```

The `ls` function only displays items whose initial characters are not "dots" unless the `all.names` parameter is set to `TRUE`.

So this is also imformative:

```
> environment(f2) $FUN
function(x, p) { x^p }
```

Comment: `environment(f2)$.orig` it a little simpler.

Comment: Agree that is more elegant. Perhaps unlike you I didn't know the answer when I started out and was showing the path I traveled to get the answer. I had gotten discouraged about that approach when I tried: `ls( environment(f2) ) #[1] "FUN"`. `ls.str` and `lsf.str` were likewise unrevealing.

Comment: the hidden variable had me going for a bit too.

Comment: After reading `?ls` again I was reminded that I once knew and then forgot about the `all.names` option.